# Implementation of Coordinate Descent in Python isn't converging

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to create a basic Linear Regression Model implementing Coordinate Descent (I have made it inherit from OrdinaryLinearRegression, because it implements the same predict and score functions).

Using the loss function as the Residual Sum of squares:

> = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>N</sub> ‖−‖<sup>2</sup>

Our gradient descent should be:

> ′=  −  <sup>2</sup>⁄<sub>N</sub> (−)

Implementing the code:

```
def scalingfeatures(X):
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(X)
    return scaler.transform(X)

class OrdinaryLinearRegressionCoordinateDescent(OrdinaryLinearRegression):

    def __init__(self,lr,num_iter):
        self.lr = lr
        self.num_iter = num_iter

    def lossfunction(self,X,y,w):
        m = np.size(y)    
        #Cost function in vectorized form
        y_pred = X @ w
        # J = 1/N * Sum((ẏ - y)**2)
        J = float((1./(2*m)) * (y_pred - y).T @ (y_pred - y))  
        return J

    def fit(self,X,y):
        X = scalingfeatures(X)
        X = np.concatenate((np.ones((X.shape[0],1)),X),axis=1)
        m,n = X.shape

        np.random.seed(42)
        w = np.random.randn(n,1)
        y = y.reshape(-1,1)

        for iter in range(self.num_iter):
            for j in range(n):
                #Coordinate descent in vectorized form
                X_j = X[:,j].reshape(-1,1)
                y_pred = X @ w 
                gradient =  X_j.T @ (y_pred-y)
                w[j] = w[j] - self.lr * (2/n) * gradient
            loss = self.lossfunction(X,y,w)
            print(loss)


        self.w = w
        return self

OLRCD = OrdinaryLinearRegressionCoordinateDescent(lr=0.05,num_iter=500)
train = OLRCD.fit(X,y)
print("The training MSE for ORLGD is: ",train.score(X,y))
```

When I run the code, I get that with every iteration the loss only increases...

Comment: What library provides the OrdinaryLinearRegression class or how is it defined?

Comment: I wrote the OrdinaryLinearRegression class, and it uses the closed-form solution.
I didn't attach it here because in regards to the fit function, it doesn't reference the parent class at all, and I didn't want to add too much unnecessary code.